# NullReferenceException at System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1.AddLast(T value)

Tags: c#, multithreading, linked-list, nullreferenceexception

I have a `LinkedList<T>` in my project where I add and remove a lot of elements (few hundred per second). This happens from multiple threads synchronized via locks.

Now sometimes (maybe every few 100.000 elements) I get a `NullReferenceException` "inside" the `AddLast` method, so the top entry of the stack trace is as following:

> at System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1.AddLast(T value)

Does someone have an idea why this could happen and how I can avoid this?

A simple/stupid try->catch->repeat would be my best idea, but thats more a dirty workaround...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This happens from multiple threads synchronized via locks.

I suspect you forgot to lock in one place, basically. Is that possible, or are you *certain* you only access it within a single place?

For example, I can see how you'd get that exception if you had one thread removing the final element in the list at the same time as another thread was adding a new element.

Rather than exposing the "raw" linked list, I suggest you try to only ever access it directly from a single class, which can take responsibility for all the locking (and which should be very, very simple).

Comment: The access is already managed by a single class - I will check again, if I did forget a lock someehere...

Comment: You forgot a lock. Even if you didn't, you did. ;)

Comment: Ok, forgot the lock on one place and now tested a few million elements without it happening again, so I guess it is fixed. Thanks...

Comment: This error is occurring pretty randomly for me in ASP.NET MVC in an @helper Razor script in App_Code.  I'm not calling LinkedList.AddLast/First, but I'm seeing this error occur in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.BrowserLinkExecutionListener.OpenRenderRange.

Comment: @Triynko: It's impossible for us to help you with that little context, I'm afraid. I suggest you ask a new question.